# JavaScript alert not working in Symfony Twig

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, alert

This code is not executing JavaScript. What I need is when I click anywhere on the table with id="articles", an alert message should be displayed. I am using Symfony and Twig template. As suggested in the comments I have added base.html.twig also.

This is index.html.twig

index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}SymphArt Articles{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% if articles %}
    <table id="articles" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Article Title</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for article in articles %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ article.title }}</td>
                <td><a href="./article/{{ article.id }}" class="btn btn-dark">Show</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete-article" data-id="{{ article.id }}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    {% else %}
        <p>No articles to display</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script>
var art = document.getElementById('articles');

if(art) {
    art.addEventListener('click', e => {
        alert("clicked");
    });
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Below is base.html.twig

base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {#{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}#}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {#{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}#}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>

        {{ include('inc/navbar.html.twig') }}

        <div class="container">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>    

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to add a JS event listener to a twig variable (`articles`). Maybe you wanted to use `art`?

Comment: yeah tried that. art.addEventListener also didn't work.

Comment: Then you need to do some debugging, as I [cannot reproduce this problem](https://jsfiddle.net/m0kxs5qr/). Side note: I also see you're not closing the second `<td>` in your loop.

Comment: Okay thanks for that. But the same code works well with html and JavaScript when I tested without twig. Is there anything else we need to add to make js work in twig?

Comment: Where HTML came from does not affect the behaviour in the browser. It does not matter if it's pure HTML, Twig or any other templating engine that produced the page's source.

Comment: Well it is definitely `art` NOT `articles` so you should correct that part in your question.  Also, please add base.html.twig  so we can see when these blocks get loaded.

Comment: Edited the question with art.addEventListener and also added base.html.twig

Comment: What have you tried to debug the prpoblem? Have you checked the **generated** markup for problems? Also, is there any error message?

Comment: There is no errors message in the page or in the console. Sorry I don't get what is generated markup?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your javascript is executing before your page is finished loading, so it is trying to find id="articles" before there is any.
Try wrapping your js code in a window.onload like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var art = document.getElementById('articles');

    if(art) {
        art.addEventListener('click', e => {
            alert("clicked");
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @exit_eden. That was it! Much appreciated.